# Guava CacheLoader throw and catch custom exceptions

Tags: java, guava, google-guava-cache

I am attempting to use the Google Guava Cache to cache by service related objects. On cache miss, I use my REST client to fetch the object. I know that I can do this in the following way:

```
CacheLoader<Key, Graph> loader = new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
     public Graph load(Key key) throws InternalServerException, ResourceNotFoundException {
       return client.get(key);
     }
   };
   LoadingCache<Key, Graph> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(loader)
```

Now, `client.getKey(Key k)` actually throws `InternalServerException` and `ResourceNotFoundException`. When I attempt to use this cache instance to get the object, I can catch the exception as `ExecutionException`.

```
try {
  cache.get(key);
} catch (ExecutionException e){

}
```

But, I would like to specifically catch and handle the exceptions that the CacheLoader I have defined is throwing(i.e. `InternalServerException` and `ResourceNotFoundException`).

I'm not sure if checking whether the instance of `ExecutionException` is one of my own exceptions would work either, cause the signature of load() method actually throws `Exception` and not `ExecutionException`. Even if I could use `instanceof`, it doesn't seem very clean. Are there any good appraoches for addressing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [javadocs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#get(K)):

> ExecutionException - if a checked exception was thrown while loading
> the value. (ExecutionException is thrown even if computation was
> interrupted by an InterruptedException.)
>
> UncheckedExecutionException - if an unchecked exception was thrown while loading the value

You need to check cause of caught ExecutionException by calling getCause():

```
} catch (ExecutionException e){
    if(e.getCause() instanceof InternalServerException) {
        //handle internal server error
    } else if(e.getCause() instanceof ResourceNotFoundException) {
        //handle resource not found
    }
}
```